Is it valid to curse someone's women to lose chastity?
Mahabharata karna parva:
उत शल्य विजानीहि हन्त भूयो ब्रवीमि ते |
यदप्यन्योऽब्रवीद्वाक्यं बाह्लीकानां विकुत्सितम् ||५७||
सती पुरा हृता काचिदारट्टा किल दस्युभिः |
अधर्मतश्चोपयाता सा तानभ्यशपत्ततः ||५८||
बालां बन्धुमतीं यन्मामधर्मेणोपगच्छथ |
तस्मान्नार्यो भविष्यन्ति बन्धक्यो वै कुलेषु वः ||५९||
Translation
Or Shalya, know that I tell you again
Whatever else he said, the words of the Bahlikas were disgusting
The chaste Kachidartta was stolen by thieves in the past
She came to them unrighteously and cursed them
That you have unjustly treated me as a child and a relative
Therefore women will become hostages in your families
Was it Dharmic on her part to curse the robber's women?
I have never heard such a curse before.

Women do seem get to be cursed due to the action of their male relatives. Even Gandhari while cursing Krishna, stated that the women of Yadu dynasty would also share the same fate as that happened to the Kurus.
